# Load CSV file from Dropbox for Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher, dropbox

I saved my CSV file on dropbox and I want to Load them on Neo4j.

The link for the shared **Users Node** csv file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kibjeea5e4cks1/users.csv?dl=0

This is the cypher

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100
        
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kibjeea5e4cks1/users.csv?dl=0" AS line
        
CREATE(u:User{userId: toInt(line.Id), username: line.UserName, fullname: line.FullName})
```

The Neo4j version I am using is Neo4j Enterprise version 3.0.9.

The result showed that it successfully created the Users Node but it created over 300 Nodes with no user name and full name. Even though there are 9 nodes with a user name and full name on the CSV file.  What am I missing?

I tried to change the URL from the shared link to the **download link** but the error **Couldn't load the external resource** showed up.

Comment: I am on Neo4j 3.1.5, and I can reproduce your error with the Dropbox link. If I am putting the file into the import folder and run the LOAD CSV from local file it works as expected.

Comment: @Fabio I can't put the file in to import folder because the Neo4j server is on azure. Or is there away that I can do this on Neo4j Server deployed on azure

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you switch from dropbox to gDrive the issue seems to not be an issue.  I dropped your csv in my drive account and it seems to work.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 100
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRANVgt-GZf0Un8dyrf7YPITDgAIBzTwjTcqOu_G7mBhGKOEZskf6Mt2oTdInyQ-wLPE0aOzsW6lVD_/pub?gid=5399540&single=true&output=csv" AS line
CREATE(u:User{userId: toInt(line.Id), username: line.UserName, fullname: line.FullName})
```

File > Publish to the web

[image]

1. Pick the tab you want
2. Select csv as the published format
3. Click Publish

And you will get back a public url to the csv

[image]

Comment: Yes it worked. Did you make it public and get the shared link

Comment: Can you tell me how you get the link? I tried to follow the steps suggested on https://www.labnol.org/internet/direct-links-for-google-drive/28356/. But it is not working

Comment: Sorry, i should have added that to the answer, choose... `File > Publish to the web...` then pick teh tab you want and select csv and it will provide you a public link

Answer (score 4):

The link you are using is not the file by itself, but the dropbox page to see the file :

```
$ curl -i --raw https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kibjeea5e4cks1/users.csv?dl=0
HTTP/2 302
server: nginx
date: Mon, 24 Jul 2017 14:46:44 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
content-length: 0
location: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/Z2KG0dzjBlHuMnIXyApZvBZFICVBXnLErAeLwlrkH46xnjg5yfd59ZfboKUpCNdo/file
```

You should try with the file direct link :

```
$ curl -i --raw https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/content_link/Z2KG0dzjBlHuMnIXyApZvBZFICVBXnLErAeLwlrkH46xnjg5yfd59ZfboKUpCNdo/file
HTTP/2 200
server: nginx
date: Mon, 24 Jul 2017 14:47:46 GMT
content-type: text/csv; charset=utf-8
content-length: 231
```

Comment: I've tried that but the error can't load the csv file showed up

Answer (score 3):

This occurs because the link https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kibjeea5e4cks1/users.csv?dl=0 returns a HTML page instead of a CSV file.

Take a look in this Cypher query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "https://www.dropbox.com/s/6kibjeea5e4cks1/users.csv?dl=0" AS line
RETURN line LIMIT 3
```

The output:

```
╒══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╕
│"line"                                                                │
╞══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╡
│{"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\" xmlns:fb=\"http://ogp.me/ns/fb#\" x│
│ml:lang=\"en\" class=\"maestro\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\│
│">":"<head><link href=\"https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/css/accou│
│nt/emails-vflCV9b0W.css\" type=\"text/css\" crossorigin=\"anonymous\" │
│rel=\"stylesheet\" />"}                                               │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\" xmlns:fb=\"http://ogp.me/ns/fb#\" x│
│ml:lang=\"en\" class=\"maestro\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\│
│">":"<link href=\"https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/css/deprecated/│
│components/multiaccount_login_modal-vflNhUM8J.css\" type=\"text/css\" │
│crossorigin=\"anonymous\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />"}                     │
├──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│{"<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=\"en\" xmlns:fb=\"http://ogp.me/ns/fb#\" x│
│ml:lang=\"en\" class=\"maestro\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\│
│">":"<link href=\"https://cfl.dropboxstatic.com/static/css/font_paper_│
│atlas_grotesk-vflEbKJso.css\" type=\"text/css\" crossorigin=\"anonymou│
│s\" rel=\"stylesheet\" />"}                                           │
└──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

To solve it try getting the direct download link from DropBox (if it is possible) or change to another storage tool.

Comment: I did mention this on my question